# How to assemble a WAV file?

Tags: c#, audio, wav

After having successfully received and extracted audio samples from Ethernet UDP packets at the PC, I need to assemble them to a WAV file, in C#.

Any example code? Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't help but think that the recording and transmission parts of this question are beside the point.  It's more that, given a bunch of samples, how do you assemble them into a wav file, right?

Answer (score 2):

I used this page to understand WAV format:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

It's missing some wrinkles I found in *reading* real-world WAV files, but it should be good enough info for *writing* them, and pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The following article doesn't provide the exact source code that you need, but reading it and the four blog posts that are listed in it should steer you in the correct direction.

http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2010/05/03/10006604.aspx